# Cannot boot from DVD 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot

Am trying to install for dual boot system. OK on one XP computer but on XP laptop I receive following message  -  "unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.  Not present pae. Don't understand what is meant by pae. Have burnt two DVDs one on each machine, and whilst both work on the PC, both come up with the same message on the laptop.
Can anyone please point me in the right direction to correct this error.
Thanks,
Roy

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE and also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider trying to install a less resource intensive Ubuntu variant such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu? I have Xubuntu on my post-XP machine and it works great. I sincerely hope this helps!

Yours truly,

Juan